# Compatibility matrix for ActiveMQ Classic and Apache ActiveMQ-CPP

Tags: activemq-classic, activemq-cpp

I am currently working on a project in which a C++ application embeds Apache [activemq-cpp](https://github.com/apache/activemq-cpp) version **3.9.3.p1** in order to address an ActiveMQ Classic **5.x**

I would like to know if this version of the activemq-cpp lib is correct to work with this version of the broker or if, on the contrary, I would have to change my version of the activemq-cpp lib

If possible I would like to have a compatibility matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveMQ-CPP can communicate via the STOMP or OpenWire protocols. Neither one of these protocols has changed in years, and both of them are supported by both ActiveMQ Classic and ActiveMQ Artemis. Therefore, you shouldn't have any compatibility issues.

The [latest release](https://activemq.apache.org/components/cms/download/) of ActiveMQ-CPP is 3.9.5 which came out in June 2022. The version you're using (i.e. 3.9.3) was released in May 2018. Therefore, I recommend you upgrade to the latest version.